# How to make Android Widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to make some widgets for android apps in flutter is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Somme searching suggests it is possible, although as a caveat, I also see suggestions that it may not be very efficient (in terms of performance) so probably wise to not get too complicated. https://medium.com/@ashishgarg1998/how-to-create-home-screen-app-widgets-in-flutter-ce3458f3638e seems like a good point-of-entry.

Answer (score -1):

you can open this link for reference
https://flutteragency.com/android-widgets-flutter-remember-simple-points/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).